# AngularJS live data?

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

Im working on c# mvc project, with angularjs.

I have 2 questions.

1. If I have a list of users. Anf I have 3 controllers(views) which uses the users list, how can I connect them to 1 "data member" which contains the list, and when 1 controller updates the list, the others updating too.
2. How can I connect the list of the users to database, and when something is changes in the e db, the list changing too?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). It allows for connected clients to be updated by activity on the server. So you could potentially write something that, when the user table is updated by anybody, your SignalR hub then sends a blast to all currently connected clients with the new users.

Comment: Actually, that's what I use now. I need the answer for tge first question to handle the situation with my signalr.